# How to copy a directory to multiple destination directories?

Tags: linux

I have a directory which contains multiple files and directories. How do I copy the directory and all its contents to multiple different directories? That is, the same content needs to be copied to multiple directories.

Comment: Solution on Super User: [link](https://superuser.com/a/1064516/432690). There's probably a similar answer here on U&L SE as well.

Answer (score 2):

#### Not possible with `cp` alone

`cp` only copies to ***one*** destination.

From [man cp](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cp)

```
Copy SOURCE to DEST, or multiple SOURCE(s) to DIRECTORY.
```

So you'd need to run the command twice, once for each destination.

#### Other methods

It is possible, however, by using *other* commands in conjunction with `cp`.

From [How to copy a file to multiple directories in Linux](https://net2.com/how-to-copy-a-file-to-multiple-directories-in-linux/)

**`xargs`**

```
echo directory_1 directory_2 | xargs -n 1 cp file_1
```

For a directory, add `-r`

```
echo directory_1 directory_2 | xargs -n 1 cp -r source_directory
```

**`find`**

```
find directory1 directory2 -exec cp file.txt {} \;
```

For a directory, add `-r`

```
find directory1 directory2 -exec cp -r source_directory {} \;
```

**loop in a shell**

```
for dir in *; do [ -d “$dir” ] && cp /full_path/file.txt “$dir” ; done
```

For a directory, add `-r`

```
for dir in *; do [ -d “$dir” ] && cp -r /full_path_to/source_directory “$dir” ; done
```

**`parallel`**

```
parallel cp -v /etc/resolv.conf ::: /directory1/, /directory2/
```

For a directory, add `-r`

```
parallel cp -r source_directory ::: /directory1/, /directory2/
```

#### Using `tee` en lieu of `cp`

From the same link

```
tee ~/directory1/file1 ~/directory2/file1 < ~/file1
```

or

```
tee ~/directory1/file1 ~/directory2/file1 < ~/file1 >/dev/nul
```

Comment: In your `find` variants, one would need to be sure that the directories don’t contain anything else (or one could add restrictions to the `find` commands). In the `for` loop variants, the `-d` test can be avoided by asking only for directories initially (`for dir in */`).

Comment: Ah yes... for the loop: `for dir in */; do cp -r /full_path_to/source_directory “$dir” ; done`. For `find` variants, do you mean the destination directories? I've just tested the `find dir ...` command (on OSX), with empty destination directories and just one file in the source directory, and it did a crazy endless recursive copy. There's clearly something not right with that command.
`

Comment: Yes, the destination directories. Copying a file on its own will be OK, but copying a directory will cause `find` to go down the newly-created target directory as well, resulting in a loop (until the paths become too long). You need to add a restriction such as `-maxdepth` or a judicious use of `-prune`.

Answer (score 0):

All tools I know of can have only a single destination, you simply need to run `cp` (or e.g. `rsync`) twice:

```bsh
cp -r dir target1
cp -r dir target2
```

Answer (score 0):

If the list of dst dirs is in an array variable, you'd likely want to use a `for` loop:

```
srcdir=src/dir
dstdirs=( some/dir some/other/dir dir3 dir4 )
for dir in "${dstdirs[@]}"; cp -a -- "$srcdir" "$dir/"; done
```

(in zsh/bash/ksh93/mksh syntax above, using the `-a` option of GNU `cp` which copies everything).

You may want to consider what to do if any of the `cp` command fails: abort the loop, report it in the overall exit status...

To copy only the contents and not the `dir` itself, replace `"$srcdir"` with `"$srcdir/."`.

With `zsh` (and a `tar` implementation that supports a `-C` option to `cd` into a directory before (un)taring), you can also do:

```
tar -C $srcdir -cf - . > >(tar -C dir1 -xpf -) \
                       > >(tar -C dir2 -xpf -) \
                       > >(tar -C dir3 -xpf -)
```

Which reads the contents of `$srcdir` only once and *tee*s it for extraction by three `tar` commands running concurrently.